# Python flask server, how to message a thread of another request?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a python threaded flask web server which performs expensive tasks on each request it receives. E.g.

```
1) CLIENT --> REQUEST1 --> SERVER
2) Server performing expensive task for request1...
3) CLIENT --> REQUEST2 --> SERVER
4) Server Performing expensive tasks for request1 and request2 in parallel...
5) Server sends complete response for request1 (or request2)
6) Server sends complete response for request2 (or request1)
```

I want the server to stop performing its task for request1 if a second request arrives. This is how I want the server to behave:

```
1) CLIENT --> REQUEST1 --> SERVER
2) Server performing expensive tasks for request1...
3) CLIENT --> REQUEST2 --> SERVER
4) Server immediately sends (incomplete) response for request1
5) Server performing expensive tasks for request2...
6) Server sends complete response for request2
```

How can i get in request2 worker a reference to request1 worker, in order to send it a stop message?
Is it possible to achieve this in flask (or if necessary, exploiting some utility libraries)?

Comment: What version of python are you using. If it's 2.x, have you tried gevent?

Comment: I'm using python 3.x and I tried unsuccessfully to install gevent using pip3 on mac os x mavericks

Comment: Hmm... Have you looked at this page [link](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/threading.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer, but I can't explain my idea clearly enough in the comments.**

There is a not so pretty solution.
Say you have code that you execute when a request reaches your server.

```
def funcReq()
```

But what you could do instead is create a new thread, which would then execute the `funcReq()`, so that way you have a variable which is holding the thread that you are interested in pausing. You can store it somewhere (Flask has a global object that it passes to each request I believe) where it can be reached by all requests. Now you have the ability to control a thread executing `Request 1` from `Request 2`.

The problem with this solution is that you end up with creating and running twice as many threads. And that is ugly.

Comment: I'd like flask (in threaded mode) to manage threads. I'd get a reference to a thread created by flask and not by me. Probably this is not achievable, and I need to use Flask in single thread and a library such as gevent to manage threads.

Comment: I ended up in using your solution, so I accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I was looking for, using a Queue and an Event from threading library Andrey suggested.
The event is called "worker_stopped" and is set if there is no worker for a request.
The queue is called worker_to_worker ad is used to send "stop" messages from a new worker (the worker for Request2) to an old worker (the worker for request1).

the sync is made with the following code at the beginning of each request

```
if (not worker_stopped.isSet()):
  print('ordering the current worker to stop')
  worker_to_worker.put('stop')
  print('waiting that current worker has stopped')
  worker_stopped.wait()
worker_stopped.clear()
perform_expensive_task()
```

and periodically checking that there are no messages in the worker_to_worker queue

```
if (worker_to_worker.empty()):
    # continue...
else:
    print('I\'m consuming a message from the worker_to_worker queue')
    worker_to_worker.get()
    worker_to_worker.task_done()
    print('signaling that the worker stopped')
    worker_stopped.set()
    # break...
```